# How to get AdMob ads to show up at the top of my screen?

Tags: layout, admob

I've got AdMob working in my app, but it's showing up at the bottom of my screen. Does anyone know how to force it to the top of the screen? I don't want to use RelativeLayout as I already have a bunch of stuff set up with my LinearLayout.

I'm initiating AdMob via an @id reference in my main.xml and some calls in the java activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
         android:id="@+id/linearLayout"   .....this is the only line I added for my Admob reference
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         >

    <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
        android:src="@drawable/image01"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:paddingTop="10px">
    </ImageView>

    </LinearLayout>
           ....
```

Then I have this in my java activity...

```
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //create an adView
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
    String pubID = "a14d9cfd23d60cf";
    AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, pubID);
    layout.addView(adView);
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest();

    //request.setTesting(true);
    adView.loadAd(request);
```

EDIT.....SOLUTION.......

Never mind...I got it figured out.  It's all about where you place the layout id.  If I move android:id="@+id/linearLayout" down into the LinearLayout just below the one it's in now, My ad shows at the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of going about this is by placing the ad view in your XML. What you do is put it just like any other view in the top of your view hierarchy under the root LinearLayout. In other words, you will have something like:

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/linearLayout"   .....this is the only line I added for my Admob reference
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
  <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         ads:adUnitId="MY_AD_UNIT_ID"
                         ads:adSize="BANNER"/>
    <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
        android:src="@drawable/image01"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:paddingTop="10px">
    </ImageView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Take a look at http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/android/banner_xml.html for more info on this.

Comment: In the xml example at the link you provided, they have:

Comment: <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.google.example"
Are you supposed to change the com.google.example to your own package name, or do you leave it as is...even for the production released app?

Comment: Wow, I don't know what it is about that xml code in the main.xml, but ended up removing my R.java file.

Comment: @greydarrah - Yes, change the com.google.example in the line xmlns:ads lines to your package name.